# how do i round in php with keeping the two zeros

Tags: php, rounding

I have this php

```
<?php echo round($price, 2); ?>
```

and the `$price` maybe `1.0000`

i want `1.00` but i get only `1`

any ideas

Comment: You should absolutely read that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: @j0ker: Please tell me what sprintf has to do with rounding.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid `sprintf("%.3f", 3.1415) ==> "3.142"`

Comment: @nickf: Much better comment than j0ker's.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following `printf()` call should work for you:

```
<?php printf("%.2f", $price); ?>
```

The documentation for this syntax is best described on the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) page.

Comment: I fail to see where any rounding takes place.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid it happens in the call to `round()` and then when printing it, it is formatted to have exactly 2 trailing decimals.

Comment: @nickf: Tim should have touched on that briefly. What happens if the PHP documentation is offline when someone looks at this answer?

Comment: If you want the rounding to be accurate (which i imagine you would do) i would never use `printf()`. `printf('%.2f | %.2f | %.2f | %.2f', 1.005, 1.015, 1.025, 1.035);` outputs **1.00 | 1.01 | 1.02 | 1.03** _(instead of 1.01 | 1.02 | 1.03 | 1.04)_ and `printf('%.3f | %.3f | %.3f | %.3f', 1.0005, 1.0015, 1.0025, 1.0035);` outputs **1.000 | 1.002 | 1.002 | 1.004** _(instead of 1.001 | 1.002 | 1.003 | 1.004)_. I use either `number_format($x, 2);` (remembering this is locale aware) or `printf('%.2f', round($x, 2));`

Comment: @buffcoredave See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding and pick a rounding .. any rounding.  It all depends on what type of rounding you prefer.

Comment: @PeterM The OP refers to $price, so if talking about currency i wouldn't say it's a matter of personal preference when it comes to rounding. If a company gets overcharged because the developer prefers to round up, i don't think that would go down too well!

Answer (score 79):

[number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) works:

`echo number_format($price, 2);`

Comment: Just be aware that (AFAIK) this is locale aware, and that with certain setups it may output `1,00` -- though I may be mistaken here.

Comment: To be safe use `number_format($price, 2, '.', '');` so your number isn't effected by locale or thousand separators.

Answer (score 15):

[number_format](http://nz.php.net/number_format) is your best bet.

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

Example:

```
<?php echo number_format(1.0000, 2, '.', ','); ?>
```

Comment: I fail to see where any rounding takes place.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid the second parameter??

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid number_format rounds implicitly, try <?php echo number_format(1.5); ?> - prints "2".

Comment: @Louis: I know what `number_format` does but you can't assume that everyone who stumbles onto your question knows what it does too. If people could be bothered to google everything we wouldn't have stackoverflow. My point was that anything that may not be immediately clear to a beginner should be touched on briefly.