# PHP: How to add leading zeros/zero padding to float via sprintf()?

Tags: php, printf, string-formatting, padding

I'm using [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to get a formatted string of some float numbers with a certain precision. In addition, I wanted to add leading zeros to make all numbers even in length. Doing that for integers is [pretty straight forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699980/413531):

```
sprintf('%02d', 1);
```

This will result in `01`. However, trying the same for a float with precision doesn't work:

```
sprintf('%02.2f', 1);
```

Yields `1.00`.

How can I add leading zeros to a float value?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Short answer:** `sprintf('%05.2f', 1);` will give the desired result `01.00`

Note how `%02` was replaced by `%05`.

**Explanation**

This [forum post](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/53968-printf-zero-padding-float-2.html#post375582) pointed me in the right direction: The first number does neither denote the number of leading zeros nor the number of total charaters to the left of the decimal seperator **but the total number of characters in the resulting string!**

**Example**

`sprintf('%02.2f', 1);` yields at least the decimal seperator "`.`" plus at least 2 characters for the precision. Since that is already 3 characters in total, the `%02` in the beginning has no effect. To get the desired "2 leading zeros" one needs to add the 3 characters for precision and decimal seperator, making it `sprintf('%05.2f', 1);`

**Some code**

```
$num = 42.0815;

function printFloatWithLeadingZeros($num, $precision = 2, $leadingZeros = 0){
    $decimalSeperator = ".";
    $adjustedLeadingZeros = $leadingZeros + mb_strlen($decimalSeperator) + $precision;
    $pattern = "%0{$adjustedLeadingZeros}{$decimalSeperator}{$precision}f";
    return sprintf($pattern,$num);
}

for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++){
    echo "$i max. leading zeros on $num = ".printFloatWithLeadingZeros($num,2,$i)."\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
0 max. leading zeros on 42.0815 = 42.08
1 max. leading zeros on 42.0815 = 42.08
2 max. leading zeros on 42.0815 = 42.08
3 max. leading zeros on 42.0815 = 042.08
4 max. leading zeros on 42.0815 = 0042.08
5 max. leading zeros on 42.0815 = 00042.08
6 max. leading zeros on 42.0815 = 000042.08
```

Comment: `The first number (...) the total number of characters in the resulting string!` not sure about this. `sprintf('%05.2f', 9999.1);` prints `9999.10` clearly more than 5 chars.

Answer (score 1):

keep it simple

```
echo sprintf("%'06.2f", 32.1);
```

> 032.10

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.