# format a floating number using PHP

Tags: php

I want to format a floating number, like this :

- **Input :** 1.7
- **output :** 01.70

I have already tried below function.

```
sprintf("%02.02f", 1.7);
```

Please help.

Comment: this could help to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739818/php-how-to-add-leading-zeros-zero-padding-to-float-via-sprintf

Comment: `sprintf("0%.2f", 1.7);` https://eval.in/520221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sprintf('%05.2f', 1.7);
```

Comment: Whilst this will work, can you add an explanation of why so people can get a better understanding?

Comment: I'm aware of an explanation too

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
sprintf('%05.2f', 1.7);
```

**Explanation**

This [forum post](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/53968-printf-zero-padding-float-2.html#post375582) pointed me in the right direction: The first number does neither denote the number of leading zeros nor the number of total charaters to the left of the decimal seperator **but the total number of characters in the resulting string!**

**Example**
`sprintf('%02.2f', 1.7);` yields at least the decimal seperator "." plus at least 2 characters for the precision. Since that is already 3 characters in total, the %02 in the beginning has no effect. To get the desired "2 leading zeros" one needs to add the 3 characters for precision and decimal seperator, making it `sprintf('%05.2f', 1.7);`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, due the explanation, the accepted answer here don't explain what or why works. My upvote for you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you tried with `str_pad()`? It's for strings, and that's what you need, because `$var = 001` is an octal and `$var = "001"` is a string.

```
   $input = 1.7;
   $output = str_pad($input, "0", 2, STR_PAD_BOTH)
```