# What is this additional format value of sprintf() function in PHP?

Tags: php

I don't understand the `02` part of the `%02.1f` additional format value of the `sprintf()`. I know that `.1` is the number of decimal places, but I don't get the `02` part.

```
echo sprintf('The distance is %02.1f', $this-car->getDistance());
```

I was looking at https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_sprintf.asp and it says that `[0-9]` "Specifies the minimum width held of to the variable value" but I don't understand what they mean.

Thank you in advance for any info that I could get.

I was looking at w3schools.com and other search results.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php - W3 Schools isn't always the best for documentation, but PHP Manual provides it too.

Comment: So zero is "Only left-pads numbers with zeros." and if so what the 2 would be? I am not getting that "Only left-pads numbers with zeros." too, if that's what it is.

Comment: I was trying this out in my code editor / browser and when I run 05 instead of 02 nothing changes on the screen. The %02.1f thing, what is the 02 part, what does it do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739818/php-how-to-add-leading-zeros-zero-padding-to-float-via-sprintf/28739819#28739819 might have the information you want, but in short, it's the minimum number of digits on both sides. So `0` will print `0.0`, but `134.24` will print `134.2`

Answer (score 2):

The position that `2` is occupying is the *minimum* field width - of the whole thing, including both sides of the decimal and the decimal point itself. Since `x.y` is already three characters, the 2 doesn't do anything here, but you can't include the `0` (which means "pad with zeros") without specifying *some* value for the field width.

But `%05.1` will absolutely produce different results from `%02.1` – as long as the number isn't so large that it already takes 5 spaces once you add the decimal to it:

```
php > sprintf('%02.1f', 0)
0.0
php > sprintf('%05.1f', 0)
000.0
```

If you leave off the `0`, it's still padded, but with spaces:

```
php > sprintf('%5.1F', 0)
  0.0
```