# concatenate a name with millisecondtime

Tags: php

I am not good with php ,I want to 'concatenate` a url, I want to add a time of millisecond at the end of it so the url be unique.

the full url is like this: `http://www.justedhak.comlu.com/images/uploaded_images1.jpg`
I want everytime add millisecond time to `uploaded_images1`

the desire result like this

```
...images/uploaded_images3214100.jpg
...images/uploaded_images3321490.jpg
...images/uploaded_images5216100.jpg
...images/uploaded_images6328490.jpg
```

I guess I have to add round() to $imagename  ?this is my code

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db);


$image=$_POST['image'];
$imagename="uploaded_images.jpg";
$imageurl="http://justedhak.comlu.com/images/."$imagename"";

     $binary=base64_decode($image);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen($imagename, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);

$sql = "insert into image (description,categorie,path) values ('$categorie','$description','$imageurl')";
```

Comment: You need to make a unique name, thats it?? @Moudiz

Comment: Maybe can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909871/getting-date-format-m-d-y-his-u-from-milliseconds

Comment: @SubinThomas yes unique name added to url . so the url upload image is unique

Comment: You need to handle file extension too?? the .jpg,.png etc?? @Moudiz

Comment: @SubinThomas yes the image always is.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use uniqid() to create unique strings. Its not just numbers. Change the following line

```
$imagename="uploaded_images.jpg";
```

with

```
$imagename = uniqid("uploaded_images").".png";  //unique string with prefix of "uploaded_images".
```

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) for more details about uniqid().

Also edit this line. Replace this line

```
$imageurl="http://justedhak.comlu.com/images/."$imagename"";
```

with

```
$imageurl = "http://justedhak.comlu.com/images/".$imagename;
```

Comment: it worked it gave me like this `uploaded_images5612cf3a71ecb.png` but please can you tell me in php how to add it to url ? is this correct ?$imageurl="http://justedhak.comlu.com/images/."$imagename"";