# convert timestamp to readable date returns +40,000 year

Tags: php, date, timestamp

can anyone convert me this timestamp into readable date `1444782970870` in php ?

I have tried `date('Y-m-d', '1444782970870')` but returns `Nov 30, 7086`

The result should be `Oct 14, 2015` i tried on [**Unix timestamp converter**](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

before you answer, please try it first.

Comment: @PaulCrovella please read first

Comment: Why are you wrapping your timestamp in strtotime? Just pass that timestamp as 2nd parameter without strtotime

Comment: Also what @devinhoward said about too many digits might matter. Try removing the last 3

Comment: @Terminus i removed the strtotime, its my mistake. why remove last 3 digits? the data is from API.

Comment: My mistake. You can leave it and it won't do anything. See this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909871/getting-date-format-m-d-y-his-u-from-milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got too many digits; you're including microseconds, but PHP wants seconds since 1970.

`date_create_from_format('U', (substr('1444782970870', 0, 10)))->format('Y-m-d');`

works for me

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Rather than using substr, it is probably best to simply divide the timestamp by 1000, Although unlikely, it will break if a larger timestamp is ever given to the script if you use substr.