# How to format time difference with micro seconds

Tags: php, time, microtime

I want to get the time difference between the two times below. The format of the time difference should be hours minutes seconds and then micro seconds. I want the final answer in this format only.

```
$start = date(' H:i:s'.substr((string)microtime(), 1, 6));
//some code
$end = date(' H:i:s'.substr((string)microtime(), 1, 6));
//$interval = ???(end  time - start time)
```

Comment: The example on the [microtime() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) pretty much answers your question. You only need to format it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered by example #2 from the [manual on microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php#example-2552):

> **Example #2 Timing script execution in PHP 5**
>
> ```
> <?php
> $time_start = microtime(true);
>   
> // Sleep for a while
> usleep(100);
>
> $time_end = microtime(true);
> $time = $time_end - $time_start;
>
> echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
> ?>
> ```

Combine this with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909871/getting-date-format-m-d-y-his-u-from-milliseconds#answer-17909891) and you get:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
   
// Do something here that takes time ...

$time_end = microtime(true);

$time = $time_end - $time_start;
$micro = sprintf("%06d", ($time - floor($time)) * 1000000);
$dateObj = new DateTime( date("Y-m-d H:i:s.$micro", $time) );

$interval = $dateObj->format("H:i:s.u");
```

If the time difference would be one minute, 23 seconds and 501293 micro seconds, then *$difference* will have this string value:

> 00:01:23.501293

Comment: i want the time difference in the format given in the ques i.e is hours minutes and seconds and microseconds