# what kind of date time format is this?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm wondering how to achieve this date format "2016-04-19T03:17:38.184+00:00" in php?

It's kinda different from ISO 8601. Please advise.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need the milliseconds, it's just `date('c');`. If you do, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909871/getting-date-format-m-d-y-his-u-from-milliseconds for some similar examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to use `date()` to show the milliseconds part because, from the manual:

> date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds.

So the only way is to use `DateTime` and pass the microseconds to the constructor. However since we only need milliseconds, we can just round it and then remove the trailing three 0's from the end later.

```
$t = microtime(true);
$milli = sprintf("%03d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000);
$d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$milli, $t) );

echo $d->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.");
echo substr($d->format("u"), 0, -3);
echo $d->format('P');
```

Outputs:

> 2016-05-22T22:41:57.294-05:00