# PHP - get milliSecond from Timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp, milliseconds, seconds

I want to get current Timestamp with millisecond. but `date()` returns Timestamp just with seconds.

Comment: [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Comment: @Bonatti This question is about millisecond but you duplicated my question with a question about date/time (just second)

Comment: Read the answers, specially about time() functions. This question shows no effort to Google what time functions exists in PHP, so I just marked one that has the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) (which is better solution because you will get exact value).

Comment: Not divide by .It should be multiply

Comment: And in any case, multiplying won't work because you can't add precision to a number. `microtime()` is the correct solution.

Comment: Oops, yes, multiply it, not divide. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have some records in my database that have timestamp, but the question is how to fetch with milliseconds. or save timestamp with milliseconds.

Comment: That's a terrible suggestion. You will still only have seconds only represented by 1000's of miliseconds.

Comment: @MajidSadr So, to be clear, by timestamp you don't mean a Unix timestamp?

Comment: @Chris I mean Unix Timestamp

Comment: @MajidSadr so why exactly microtime() is not fine? It returns time in microseconds?

Comment: EdvinTenovim Your last edit solved my problem. But Thank you @Chris

Comment: @MajidSadr His edits never actually changed the semantics of the answer though. The original said to use `microtime()` too. In any case, I'm glad you solved it. You should be able to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I moved the first part up because it is more appropriate than the second one (multiplication).

Comment: @EdvinTenovim, I would sugest you just remove the second part since it is simply mind numbingly bad and wrong. It's like suggesting using MS Paint zoom to substitute for an electron microscope

Comment: @apriede, yes, I agree about that. I should remove that part.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below code from [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909871/getting-date-format-m-d-y-his-u-from-milliseconds)

```
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
echo $now->format("m-d-Y H:i:s.u");
```

Comment: It returns negative results some times:
`05-25-2016 11:31:25.-339967296`

Comment: Has this negative value issue ever been further discussed?