# How to add milliseconds to an Datetime object in php?

Tags: php, datetime

If I have an object of type DateTime how I can add some milliseconds?

```
$date = new Datetime("2016-09-23T20:48:16.090Z");
// how to add to this date 9 milliseconds?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909871/getting-date-format-m-d-y-his-u-from-milliseconds

Comment: How about working with http://php.net/microtime

Comment: You can use DateInterval, but the smallest interval you can add seems to be a second. See http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php and http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: why do you need to add 9 milliseconds?

Comment: I want to calculate total loading time from a har file. For this I have a start date and the time in miliseconds for each request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of PHP 7.1, milliseconds and microseconds can also be easily added to DateTime using the modify method.

```
$date = new Datetime("2016-09-23T20:48:16.090Z");
$millisec = 9;

$date->modify('+ '.$millisec.' milliseconds');
var_dump($date);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-09-23 20:48:16.099000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For lower PHP versions like PHP 5.6 you could try:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $micro_date = microtime();
    $date_array = explode(" ",$micro_date);
    $date = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",$date_array[1]);
    echo $date."." .round( $date_array[0] * 1000)."Z";
```

Answer (score 0):

##### PHP 7.1+

**Non string manipulation way** to set microseconds is to use [**`DateTime::setTime($h, $m, $s, $µs)`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php):

```php
$date = new Datetime("2016-09-23T20:48:16.090Z");

$milliseconds = 9;
$ms_in_microseconds = $milliseconds * 1000; // 1000ms in 1 µs

$date->setTime( $dt->format('H'), $dt->format('i'), $dt->format('s'), $ms_in_microseconds );
// in this case, it will run: $date->setTime( 20, 48, 16, 9000 );
```

A bit tedious, but reliable :)