# DateTime with microseconds for negative timestamps(<1970)

Tags: php, datetime

How to correctly instantiate DateTime from Unix timestamp with microseconds?

```
php > echo (DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', '-128649660.000000'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u U.u');
1965-12-03 23:59:00.000000 -128649660.000000
php > echo (DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', '-128649659.999998'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u U.u');
1965-12-03 23:59:01.999998 -128649659.999998
```

As you can see, `2us` diff in timestamp gives `2s-2us` diff in total.
I believe is the correct result is `1965-12-03 23:59:00.000002`.

How can I reach it convenient way, without manual recalculations for negative timestamps?

---

*May be I should always interpret 'U.u' format as 'U + 0.u' value?

I mean `u` is not microseconds part but a positive difference from integer part?*

Comment: Yes. What you added to the end is correct.

Comment: @Sammitch, so, we have no simple way to create correct DateTime from '-128649659.999998'? Only `createFromFormat('U\+0.u', '-128649660+0.000002')` after recalculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then my solution will be:

```
function uDate($ts) {
  $dts = floor($ts);                             // integer part
  $uts = number_format($ts - $dts, 6, '.', '');  // fraction part                    
  return DateTime::createFromFormat('U\+0.u', "$dts+$uts");
}
function uTime(\DateTimeInteface $dt) { // Reverse action
  $dts = $dt->format('U');
  $uts = $dt->format('0.u');
  return number_format($dts+$uts, 6, '.', '');
}

echo uDate('-128649659.999998')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'), PHP_EOL; // 1965-12-03 23:59:00.000002
echo uDate('-128649660.000002')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'), PHP_EOL; // 1965-12-03 23:58:59.999998
echo uDate('1544639767.999998')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'), PHP_EOL; // 2018-12-12 18:36:07.999998
```

- `floor` function can extract integer part simple, because it rounds always to "nearest smallest integer".

Answer (score 2):

One way to do is to force a calculate of the microseconds, assuming that you have negative timestamp:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', '-128649659');
$ms = (1000000-999998);
echo $date->modify("-1 second +$ms microsecond")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u U.u');
1965-12-03 23:59:00.000002 -128649660.000002
```

So basically you ignore, at first, the microseconds part. In a second moment, you do the calculation only of the microseconds part.

If you take a note, the `U.u` part will be wrong, so it has no use in this case.

Not sure if it will work for every scenario, any suggestion will be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to finagle the time string into the correct format.

```
function convertNegativeTimestamp(string $ts) {
    $parts = explode('.', $ts);
    if( count($parts) != 2 ) {
        return $ts;
    }
    $parts[0] = intval($parts[0]);
    if( $parts[0] < 0 ) {
        $parts[1] = intval(str_pad($parts[1], 6, '0'));
        $parts[1] = 1000000 - $parts[1];
        return sprintf('%d.%06d', $parts[0], $parts[1]);
    } else {
        return $ts;
    }
}
```