# PHP round precision bug?

Tags: php, rounding

Is this a bug or some math thing I don't understand?

```
round(58.900662, 2) => 58.9
```

Where is the last zero?

EDIT:
In my opinion, the documentation is lacking information.

The following code does as expected

```
number_format(round(58.900662, 2), 2) => 58.90
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i round in php with keeping the two zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493305/how-do-i-round-in-php-with-keeping-the-two-zeros)

Comment: Who said .90 and .9 are different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`round` will take care of the precision if that digit is not `0` as the last `0` has no effect in any mathematical operation.

If the number is `1.569` then `round` will return `1.57`

If you want that `0` the you can use -

```
number_format(58.900662, 2, '.', ',');
```

[number_format()](http://php.net/number_format)

Comment: Yep this is what they apparently need

Comment: This should be pointed out in the documentation. If I explicitly set the precession to two, then I want two numbers after the comma.

Comment: *two numbers after the comma.* ?

Answer (score 1):

You told it to round it to the 2nd decimal place which would be 58.90. However, 58.90 can be simplified to 58.9. It is the same number.

If you want to force the display of two decimal places you can use PHP's number_format() function.